# How to prevent images from loading on devices of certain width?

Tags: javascript, css

I don't want to set them to `display:none;` with media queries because they would still load. Is there any way to load them only if the device's width is over 500px for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load them all after the page itself has loaded using javascript, and ignore certain images if `window.innerWidth` is less than 500.

The specifics of the implementation would be determined by your own application, but I would recommend something like the following:

Replace all images with placeholders, and give the ones you may wish to hide a certain class:

```
<img src="placeholder.png" class="gt500" data-source="realimage.png">
```

You could then do something like (assuming jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 500) { return; }
    $('img.gt500').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('source'));
    });
});
```

Which will swap all the placeholders for the real images, but only if the window is wide enough.

Comment: Hmmm... Same as my suggestion but with data. You could select only images with data-source attributes ratherthan relying on a class?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a native selector for data attributes, which means you would have to iterate through all images in the DOM and reject them with a check inside the loop. This would require less markup, but be slightly slower to execute, so whichever you prefer I suppose.

Comment: Hey! sorry I didn't reply earlier but as I'm using wordpress for this I had to overwrite some media functions to insert the data-source in my thumbnails. Also, instead of `$(this).src = $(this).data('source');` I had to do it in two lines: `var img_src = $(this).data('source'); $(this).attr('src', img_src);` Anyways, thanks a lot for the help @beeglebug !

Comment: Adding a superfluous placeholder image? I'm thinking a better solution would be to use a DIV and `appendChild` the IMG tag to the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
<img src="" data="actualimagesource" />
```

Check each image, either on the server or client side: If the site's width allows the image to display, pull the string from "data" and place it in the "src" attribute.

Very similar to: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Beeglebug's solution is much more verbose than mine, I suggest looking it up in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent an image from loading except to delete it from the DOM or change it's src. Even then, it'll already have started loading, so whether it loads in full will depend on how the browser implements it, and I don't know the answer to that.

All I can suggest is that you prefix all the image srcs with a #, then do something like this:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img[src^="#"]');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
   imgs[i].setAttribute('src', imgs[i].getAttribute('src').substr(0));
}
```

if the screen width is greater than a certain number. That prevents users who have JavaScript disabled from seeing your images though, so consider the pros and cons carefully.

Comment: You will potentially get broken images on the page with this technique, although only for the time it takes for the script to run.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this server-side. [WURFL](http://dbapi.scientiamobile.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a database that's often used for mobile device sniffing, a PHP example is [here](http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2009/04/a-first-look-at-the-new-wurfl-api-for-php.html). In desktop web development browser and device sniffing is considered super bad practice. For mobile, because of the sheer number of devices and their different capabilities it's often a necessity. I believe WURFL tests the user agent string server side (amongst other things) to detect the device and will then return a bunch of information about it (including screen resolution) you could then serve different sized images based on this information.

I don't think there's a way of cleanly preventing image load at the front-end. You could loop through all images with javascript on document load and set the src attribute to an empty string if their width was greater than 500px. The problem with this is that you'd have to make sure that all your images had specific dimensions in the markup and even then some browsers won't report the width until the image has finished loading. You also couldn't guarantee that images wouldn't start download before the javascript kicked in (and not all mobile devices support js or have it turned on) This feels horribly hacky to me though.